# Is it possible to detect a block of memory was changed by stray or wild pointer on C?

Tags: c, pointers

For example, I have a block of memory allocated on C.

```
void* block = malloc(1024*10);
```

In runtime, I never change it manually. But, it might be changed because of memory corruption, stray pointer or wild pointer for example.

```
memset(straypointer, 1, 1);
```

This will happen in very very rare, BUT, it still has the chance.
So, I wonder whether is possible to know my memory block has be changed unexpected.

I guess some kind of memory pool can do it, but I don't have further idea.

Comment: Nope, you are free to shoot you in your own knee at will in C/C++. Bookkeeping every single address would be quite an overhead.

Comment: You could start a thread which checks the contents of the memory area every x second... not recommended though.

Comment: C doesn't have anything for that, but your operating system might provide debugging API that could do what you want. Still, as Samuel said, it will be quite an overhead, and you might be hunted with hayforks and fire.

Comment: Look into valgrind and malloc with guard pages.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that it just a terrible comment, (because I did not think of it first:).  You should promote it to an answer so I can give you an upvote.

Comment: @MartinJames done, thanks. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows : don't use `malloc` but [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx). Then fill the memory with whatever you want, then use [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) to protect that memory.

Then as soon as someone writes to that memory region, your program will crash (or crash into the debugger if debugged). For other systems use a similar method (depending on the system).

Comment: I may actually use this plan later myself:)

Comment: Oh.. it' not there.  I'll have to import it explicitly from Kernel32:(   I'll make a separate unit for it so I can use it across projects.

Comment: @MartinJames what is not where ??`Which SDK do you have ??

Comment: S'OK - I have it.  I mistyped the name, but I have VirtualAlloc() and VirtualAllocEx() to chose from now:)

Comment: What is the same thing on *nix?